# How to copy, paste and insert data in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, copy, paste

I'm new to visual studio c# (2015) and learning it online. It is bit confusing a bit because of different ways it's being showed.

What I'm trying to accomplish is this: The result set is showed after the I hit enter; I want to be able to copy a selected row or copy the whole result set and paste it.

Also, would like to add new rows. It's currently running and able to update the records.

Please see below code:

```
namespace Offerlist
{
  public partial class frmMain : Form
  {
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("data source = TLKCDDB05;" + 
                      " initial catalog=cabledb; integrated security=TRUE");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommandBuilder cmd = new SqlCommandBuilder();

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand
            ("select * from mc_client_offerlist where campcode like'" + 
             "%" + txtCampCode.Text + "' and offertype>0 order by crc ASC", cs);

        ds.Clear();

        da.Fill(ds);

        dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    }

    private void txtCampCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Update(ds);
            MessageBox.Show("Updated", "Update", 
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", 
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You will need to decide (and tell us) a little more about the pasting part: Where do you want to paste it? After a row? Always whole rows? Create new rows when pasting? [In several answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527728/copy-and-paste-into-a-datagridview-cell-c?rq=1) are a few lines of code you might find helpful, especially the longer code shows one way to stitch data from cell into a string. But you really also need to think about the data: Are they strings, may they contain tabs or newlines? A Cell.Value is an object and could hold all sorts of things..

Comment: Thanks Taw for that .... copying the entire row or the whole result set,  i would like to paste it on the same datagridview, creating new rows.

Comment: @ZYK What do you want to do about keys and constraints when pasting rows?

Comment: I'm not really sure about what ypu meant by keys .... the table I'm pulling the data has the id set as unique ....